# php insert values based on radio selection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a piece of code for our internal CMS and I'm struggling to add a function on our ordering system... I am no full time coder and this is just a side job so apologies for an silly mistakes etc.

Basically I have an order form that the user completes, I currently have input boxes for the user to input either our site address or an alternate address. I also have a radio button at the top of each address.

I want the user to be able to select one of the addresses and then when the form processes it looks at which address is selected and inputs this to the database. My current code is as follows;-

address for work
`<input type="radio" name="site_adr_1" value="yes">`
`<input type="text" name="site_adr_1" value="work address"/>`

address for site
`<input type="radio" name="site_adr_2" value="yes">`
`<input type="text" name="site_adr_2" value="site address"/>`

This is my code for inserting to the database;-

`//inserting data order`
`$order = "INSERT INTO`database`.`table`(`site_adr_1`,`
`)`
`VALUES`
`('$_POST[site_adr_1]',)"`
`;`

`//declare in the order variable`
`$result = mysqli_query($order);  //order executes`

`mysqli_close();`

I've researched into using `if ($_POST['site_adr_1'] == 'yes')` statement but I''m struggling to implement... any ideas?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You have both the text field and the radio button named the same. Start with renaming one of them. Then add some code that displays all post vars to see what you are getting. Should be pretty simple to figure out from there.

Comment: Hi Len_D - Thanks for your comment, if I add all the post vars at the moment my script will just add both values as they are both listed i.e post-site_adr_1, post-site_adr_2. I've not added a specific column to the database as again I didnt know if I could call it 'address' rather than having both names. if I call the radio 'adr_1' and then use the following statement `if ($_POST['adr_1'] == 'yes') then ($_POST['site_adr_1']) else $_POST['adr_2'] == 'yes') then ($_POST['site_adr_2'])`

Comment: mysqli syntax is slightly different. it is mysqli(connection, query), instead of old mysql(query)

Comment: Dimitri -  It was on mysql but I'm converting across to mysqli

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off doing something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="addressType" value="site"> 
<input type="radio" name="addressType" value="work"> 
<input type="text" name="address" value=""/>
```

Then you just check the value of the $_post['$addressType']. Create a column called AddressType and one called address. Then you can save the address and know what type it is.

Comment: Hi Len, on my form the user has to physically type in an input box what the address is whether it be site or work this is why I need the post to determine which has been completed using the radio button and then input the values to the database - the extra problem I have is converting either site/work address into a database column called 'address'

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer I gave you solves your problem. read it again.

Comment: Hi Len, yes I understand your answer but this does not assist my problem. I have a form which has two sets of input boxes which the user can complete (the work address is pre-completed), there is a corresponding radio button to tell the form which address is to be used i.e work or site. Once they submit the form I want it to check which address is selected then copy the input box values to the database. I only want one column in the database which either address will be inserted to. Does this make sense?

Comment: Len, this is my current code `if ($_POST['works'] == 'yes') 
then 
'$_POST['$works_adr_1']' 
'$_POST['$works_adr_2']' 
'$_POST['$works_adr_3']' 
'$_POST['$works_adr_4']' 
else 
if ($_POST['site'] == 'yes') 
then
'$_POST['$site_adr_1']' 
'$_POST['$site_adr_2']' 
'$_POST['$site_adr_3']' 
'$_POST['$site_adr_4']' 
else 
if ($_POST['other'] == 'yes') 
then
'$_POST['$other_adr_1']' 
'$_POST['$other_adr_2']' 
'$_POST['$other_adr_3']' 
'$_POST['$other_adr_4']' `

Comment: but this doesnt work because I cannot convert these values (once selected) to the database tables which are del_adr_1, del_adr_2 etc etc can you help? The radio buttons are obviously named site, works, other

Comment: I think you need to re-explain what you are trying to do. All of these address fields are coming from where, one form? The original question showed two address options. What are all of these others?

Comment: Hi Len, Sorry to confuse. I have an order form where the user selects a radio box to choose which address they want to use (x3)... and in here the user has to fill in the corresponding input box. When they run the form it is supposed to check which radio is selected and then copy the values from the input box and transfer to the database. The radio boxes are called site, works & other. The input boxes are called site_adr, works_adr & other_adr. The database column is called address. I hope you can follow my description?

Comment: Hi Len, did you get chance to re-review/edit your original answer?